# Deriving Friedmann equation with density parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got some serious problems with solution of Friedmann equation in form:
$$\left(\dot{a} \right)^{2} = H_{0}^{2}[\Omega_{0} a^{-1} + (1-\Omega_{0})a^{2}],$$
where $\Omega_{0} =$ positive const(density parameter), $H_{0} =$ positive const(Hubble parameter), and variable $a$ called *scale factor* is respected with the present time($t=t_{0}$). This problem appears in Andrew Liddle's *Introduction to modern cosmology*. I want to know, what does the $H_{0}t_{0}$ equals. In this book the author gave us two solutions, how could it looks like:
$$H_{0}t_{0} = \frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\Omega_{0}}}ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\Omega_{0}}}{\sqrt{\Omega_{0}}}=\frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\Omega_{0}}}sinh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-\Omega_{0}}{\Omega_{0}}}$$
My attempts:
I've tried to separate the variables:
$$\frac{da}{\sqrt{\Omega_{0}a^{-1}+(1-\Omega_{0})a^{2}}} =H_{0}dt $$
Then integrate the equation:
$$\int\frac{da}{\sqrt{\Omega_{0}a^{-1}+(1-\Omega_{0})a^{2}}} = \int H_{0}dt $$
and that's all.I know that i could make some substition to get an antiderrivative in form like $ln(\sqrt{u^{2}-1}+u)$ but then a lot of $a$ variables appears in logarithm, so i'm not really sure if it's gonna work.
I will be glad for every hint.
Edit:

There is a hint in this book:

*Change the integration variable $a$ in the expression $t_{0} = \int_{0}^{t_{0}} dt$*

Edit no.2: 
I haven't notice that autor suggested, that a=1, so it could be equation:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{da}{\sqrt{\Omega_{0}a^{-1}+(1-\Omega_{0})a^{2}}} = \int_{0}^{t_{0}} H_{0}dt, $$
with definite integrals obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{da}{\sqrt{\Omega_{0}a^{-1}+(1-\Omega_{0})a^{2}}} = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{a}{\Omega_{0}+(1-\Omega_{0})a^{3}}} da $$
Let $x=a^{3/2} \quad\to\quad dx=\frac32 a^{1/2}da$
$$I= \frac23 \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\Omega_{0}+(1-\Omega_{0})x^2}} dx $$
Let $(1-\Omega_{0})x^2=\Omega_{0}t^2 \quad\to\quad x=\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_{0}}{1-\Omega_{0}}}t$
$$I= \frac{2}{3\sqrt{1-\Omega_0}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{1-\Omega_{0}}{\Omega_{0}}}}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$$
$$I =\frac{2}{3\sqrt{1-\Omega_0}} \big[\sinh^{-1}(t)\big]_{t=0}^{t=\sqrt{\frac{1-\Omega_{0}}{\Omega_{0} }}} $$
$$I= \frac{2}{3\sqrt{1-\Omega_0}} \sinh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\Omega_{0}}{\Omega_{0}}} \right)$$

$\sinh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-\Omega_{0}}{\Omega_{0}}}= \ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\Omega_{0}}}{\sqrt{\Omega_{0}}}\quad$ results from a well known relationship between $\sinh^{-1}$ and $\ln$, see Eq.(1) in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicSine.html